# How to implement HTTP POST (with JSON body) in App Inventor 2?

Tags: json, http-post, ibm-cloud, app-inventor

Brand new to this and spent a good deal of time searching for this information. Got it working on Kinetise, but those chaps want $100 month. Not!

I am using Bluemix with a cloudant nosql database and successfully populating that database with weatherstation sensor data.

Here is my HTTP POST DATA and a SAMPLE RETURN value;

**The API URL is**,
https://6bf8b7fb-a253-4433-a8e3-20da37e95dee-bluemix.cloudant.com/dpjg-sensorlog3/_find

**The code below created with Postman works perfectly from Postman!!!**

```
POST /dpjg-sensorlog3/_find HTTP/1.1
Host: 6bf8b7fb-a253-4433-a8e3-20da37e95dee-bluemix.cloudant.com
Authorization: Basic dHRlcnNlZW5ncnRpbmV2ZW5zd2Vyc3R1OmJmNGMzZmRkOTFjMzVjNDYyN2JmNDBiN2ViYTFkNjBhMzkyjhhZDc=
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 666e0601-41de-de9a-e8e4-346cc353eb71

{
  "selector": {
    "tme": {
      "$gt": 0
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "tme",
    "oat",
    "sot",
    "oah",
    "rnt",
    "lux",
    "bxt",
    "spv",
    "btv",
    "hea"
  ],
  "sort": [
    {
      "tme": "desc"
    }],
  "limit":1
}
```

**The sample response is**,
    {"docs":[
    {"tme":"2016-04-29T19:36:18-    04:00","oat":"77.2","sot":"78.0","oah":66.1,"rnt":0,"lux":73,"bxt":0,"spv":"4.3"    ,"btv":"3.6","hea":33024}
    ]}`

I cannot figure out how to set this up in an app inventor 2 block.

I don't know what to use for the property URL on the DESIGN page nor what to populate in the .posttext text input.

Comment: Use the `web` component and set the `url` and `request headers`, then use the `PostText`method to post the JSON string, see also something similar [here](https://puravidaapps.com/dropbox.php). Just try something and if you get stuck, **edit** your question and post a screenshot of what you have tried.

Comment: I have tried many combinations using my judgment and can't get it to work. Here are my specific questions; 1. What do I use for the Web component URL property, my API URL?, 2. How do I properly build the POST as I have all the required information to do so I just don't know where to put it. 3. Sounds like the JSON query goes in the SPECIFIED TEXT of the POSTTEXT method but how do I apply the remaining portions of that POST data? Again, I have tried many differents combinations trying to figure this out. I'll wing something else out and post screenshots.

Comment: 1) yes 2) put the JSON string into a text block and assign it to the PostText block 3) what are the remaining portions? See again my previous comment and **show us a screenshot of what you have tried**.

Comment: It was the Request Headers component I was missing. Took awhile to get that working too, using lists and sublists.

Comment: You might want to post your solution as answer.

Answer (score 2):

As the original poster mentioned in the comments above, you will likely need to set the RequestHeaders of your Web component.  Here is a screenshot...

[image]